# Problem with \mathbb and superscript number

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathbb

I wrote `\mathbb{R^2}` in the editor, however what gets printed in the pdf is the turnstile symbol in the exponent instead of 2.

I have the following packages:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

The other numbers are also replaced by logical symbols.

Comment: `\mathbb{R}^2` is the correct syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Haven't used LateX in a while !!

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `amssymb` automatically loads `amsfonts`, so you don't need the penultimate line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The manual of `amsfonts` specifies that `\mathbb` should only be used with ***capital letters***.

What happens when other characters are in the argument of `\mathbb` is almost random.

Type `\mathbb{R}^2`, which is more sensible also on a semantic point of view.

The problem would present also with `\mathcal`.

Answer (score 5):

You probably don’t actually want a blackboard-bold numeral  here.  There is one in Unicode, so in `unicode-math`, your code would do exactly what you said.